# Save unicode characters in DB using java

Tags: java, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I need to save some uni-code characters in Sql server 2005 DB with JDBC, When i try to save "O’CON" into DB column having type NVarchar using a stored procedure it saves "O?CON" `(where ’ character is not `` or ')

I did some R&D and found that i need to add `useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8` some where in my `DBcon.properties` file that contains all the details of DB connection,

Can some one help me out where to add this into properties file or it i can add it at run time when i create a connection object.

Or if someone can help me how to save unicodes characters in DB using java.

Thanks.

Comment: I see from some of your earlier questions that you may be using Eclipse. If so, then right-click on the name of your .java file in Package Explorer and choose "Properties". Check the "Text file encoding" setting for that file. Is it `UTF-8`? `Cp1252`? something else?

Comment: @GordThompson its UTF-8

Comment: What JDBC driver are you using? I just tested using "Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server" and I could not recreate your issue, even after trying several different settings for `sendStringParametersAsUnicode`, `useUnicode`, and `characterEncoding`.

Comment: Correction: I did get my test to fail with "Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server" when I used `sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false` in the connection string. `useUnicode` and `characterEncoding` didn't seem to make any difference. (I believe the latter two are for MySQL, not Microsoft SQL Server.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to database you use connect string specific to your database and driver.

I used MS MSQ long time ago but I remember that they had `jtds` driver. Connect string for such driver looks like:

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://hostname:1433/my_database;useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

But from that time MS create their own JDBC driver and if you use it then I think you can add:

```
sendStringParametersAsUnicode=true
```

to your connect string. It is decribed at http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378988.aspx

In a case of problems show us your connect string and code where it is used.